# How can I determine the source of this NoSuchFieldError?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, amazon-emr

I'm trying to setup hbase on AWS's EMR service. And I'm trying to use EMRFS as the hdfs for it. But when I start the instance the hbase master just goes into a crash loop.

From reading about `NoSuchFieldError`s and from the presence of the `com.google.inject` I think that there might be a problem with the `CLASSPATH`, or else one or more libraries were complied against wrong versions.

The errors at crash:

```
1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSBaseModule.provideEntityStore(EmrFSBaseModule.java:75)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSBaseModule.provideEntityStore(EmrFSBaseModule.java:75)
  while locating com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.dynamodb.EntityStore<com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.dynamodb.Entity>
    for field at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n2.S3NativeFileSystem2.entityStore(S3NativeFileSystem2.java:41)
  while locating com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n2.S3NativeFileSystem2
  while locating org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=s3n2)

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.initialize(EmrFileSystem.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:666)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:491)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.metrics.EmrRequestMetricCollector.collectMetrics(EmrRequestMetricCollector.java:42)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.endClientExecution(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:599)
        at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.endClientExecution(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:580)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1082)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1088)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.dynamodb.impl.NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.describeTable(NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.java:279)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.dynamodb.impl.NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.tableExists(NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.java:274)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.dynamodb.impl.NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.initialize(NativeDynamoDBEntityStore.java:225)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSProdModule.createEntityStore(EmrFSProdModule.java:231)
        at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.guice.EmrFSBaseModule.provideEntityStore(EmrFSBaseModule.java:75)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.get(ProviderMethod.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Possibly you have incompatible versions of libs.

Comment: Is there a good way to verify that?

Comment: How you start your program?

Comment: `/usr/java/latest/bin/java -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Xmx3000m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xmx512m -Dhbase.log.dir=/mnt/var/log/hbase -Dhbase.log.file=hbase-hadoop-master-ip-172-30-2-53.log -Dhbase.home.dir=/home/hadoop/hbase -Dhbase.id.str=hadoop -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/lib/native:/home/hadoop/hbase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,DRFAS org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster start`